# Is there any File-System based database in PHP?

Tags: php, database, file, server

I am using a server, which has a restriction on the database usage i.e. I can't use more than 10mb of data, in the MySQL tables. So, I am searching for a alternate way of storing data, I need a database which stores data in form of files and it is also easy to use too.

Answer (score 5):

I suggest to use [**SQLite**](http://php.net/manual/en/book.sqlite.php). This is a lightweight database that works natively in PHP and includes many of the functions that you are used to using in MySQL.

Comment: But, I don't know if they have enabled it in their server.

Comment: Check `phpinfo()` to find out exactly. This is a very popular database, so it is very likely that your hosting provider should support it.

Comment: Yep, its disabled, I've to pay to use it.

Answer (score 0):

You could try using XML files in order to save your data.

Regarding the database limit, MySQL saves the data in files as well, so that must be a limitation on MySQL itself. You could ask them if you could use another DBMS, like PostgreSQL.

Comment: Can XML be used to replace databases in PHP?

Comment: There are XML databases, you can read more at https://www.tutorialspoint.com/xml/xml_databases.htm But this is not a trivial task. Using plain XML files is only meant as a way to overcome your hosting' s problem. It is not a simple substitute for a database.

Comment: Are these Plain Files safe to use?

Comment: Safety has nothing to do with plain files. MySQL, or other DBMSs have well know file formats, so a hacker could interpret the file if one could get his hands on. File permissions, encryption, your application, the server provide safety for the files. Security through obscurity only provides a false sense of security in most cases.

Comment: For ex- if you have a XML Database which has a list of usernames and the passwords, then you can also view in a browser, but in other Db(s), its not possible.

Comment: @Sky-fiscientist This is where you save the file. If you tell MySQL to save it in a web directory, then it will be very easy to see the data. You can save the XML file outside the web or use .htaccess to deny access (though I would recommend the first way)

Answer (score 0):

Everything uses files in the end. 
You could overcome the server limitation by having mysql in a separate server which does not have this restriction. Anyhow, if your data increases, this 10 MB limit will get exceeded.

PHP allows you to connect to external systems for database connectivity. Just set the servername variable in the connection query.

Comment: The server has blocked it I can't use database in a separate server

Comment: You cant store tables in data. 
You cant use SQLite. 
You cant connect to external systems. 
How exactly will you work? 

Create your own code with files and work with them. is the only solution left. That will be some amount of work. Cant be easy if you haven't done it before.

Comment: No. I can't do that, you've to enable sqlite from the php.ini, which is not done in that server